# Node app with multiple servers under single Docker container return 404 for some servers/ports

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, pm2

I am attempting to set up a Dockerised Node app, which runs three Node servers via pm2-runtime. The three servers live within a single container. The same setup runs perfectly on localhost outside Docker, but I am having issues with 404 errors being returned in the Docker version (for certain ports). Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

# Create the workdir.
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

# Install packages.
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Install pm2 globally.
RUN npm install -g pm2

# Copy source code to the container.
COPY . ./

# Run the servers with pm2-runtime.
#MD ["pm2-runtime", "process.yml"]
```

My process.yml:

```
apps:
  - script   : ./dist/foo.js
    name     : 'foo'
    instances: 2
    env    :
      NODE_ENV: production
  - script : ./dist/bar.js
    name   : 'bar'
    instances: 2
    env    :
      NODE_ENV: production
  - script : ./dist/baz.js
    name   : 'baz'
    instances: 2
    env    :
      NODE_ENV: production
```

And here is my docker-compose.yml (I do have other services defined within it, but have stripped it down to the single service for this example. I have tested with just this service and I still face the same problem):

```
version: "3"

services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
```

The problem I am facing is that while I can access the foo server on port 3000 the other servers give me a 404. It's worth noting that the bar and baz servers are accessed by axios calls. But I can't understand why they return a 404 error, when there is no problem when running locally. Also the resources in question are in a subfolder of my static folder.

What could be going on? Is there something amiss with my docker-compose ports definition?

Comment: Could you try running three instances of `foo.js` on the three different ports and seeing if the same errors occur? This would rule out any mis-configuration of the other two services.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to make service for each one of your Node app.

```
services:
foo:
  build: .
  restart: always
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=production
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
bar:
  build: .
  restart: always
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=production
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
baz:
  build: .
  restart: always
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=production
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
```